# Most recent transaction id by loan id and date

Tags: date

I have 3 columns, loan_code, tran_code, and tran_date.  For each loan_code there are several tran_codes with several tran_dates.  For each loan_code I need to get the most recent tran_code.

Currently my query says:

```
    Select loan_code, max(tran_date) as tran_date, tran_code
    from loan_table
    group by loan_code, tran_code
```

This causes duplicates of the loan_code with different tran_codes. I only need the most recent one.  I also have tried using distinct in front of loan_code but that didn't change anything.

```
    loan_code | tran_code | tran_date
    ---------------------------------
    2379778   | 37082762  | 2014-06-06
    2379778   | 39304394  | 2014-06-08
    4687613   | 35510651  | 2015-02-08
    4687613   | 37082762  | 2015-02-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT loan_code, tran_date, tran_code 
FROM loan_table table1
JOIN 
(SELECT loan_code,max(tran_date) as tran_date, tran_code
 FROM loan_table
 GROUP BY loan_code, tran_code
) table2
ON table1.loan_code= table2.loan_code
  AND table1.tran_date= table2.tran_date
  AND table1.tran_code= table2.tran_code
```